oxidising cysteine to cystine in hair shaft
Is there any non-toxic chemical/oxidising agent/catalyst that can oxidise broken disulphide bonds (UV damaged/ bleached hair) i.e. cysteine to cystine in hair shaft (without reacting with other amino acids in the hair)?
